# SQL Server Enterprise Manager 2000 error "job fails"

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, dts

I'm following the steps described below:

1. Installed SQL Server 2000 on a Windows XP Machine;
2. Opened the Enterprise Manager and created a DTS Package;
3. I have checked that I am able to run the DTS Package with no issues;

When I set this package to schedule the job fails with this error:

> The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User domain\user.  The last step to run was step 1 (TEST2).

I have done this at the machine level and domain level.

Any thoughts why it's failing? Are there any permissions within SQL Server 2000 I need to change?

I have SQL Server 2000 running on a Windows 2000 Server machine and the packages run fine without issues. I am starting to wonder if the packages just won't run on a Windows XP machine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: SQL 2000? You really should update!

Comment: What is the step doing?

Comment: Has you looked in the logs to see what that step actually got wrong?